# oauth2 authentication not working in iPhone

Tags: swift, crm, hubspot-crm

I am developing one iPhone app in which I need to implement login with hubspot.
To implement this, I used oauth2 library in swift. In this I am using below code to do authorization.
When I run the app, its navigating me to safari and asking to enter id and passwrod of Hubspot. When I enter it, its just keep me inside the website and showing 3 dots loading.

```
{
let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
consumerKey: "****",
consumerSecret: "****",
authorizeUrl: "https://app.hubspot.com/oauth/authorize",
accessTokenUrl: "https://api.hubapi.com/oauth/v1/token",
responseType : "code"
)
oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: URL(string: "myapp://"), scope: "contacts", state:"code", success: { (credentials, response, parameters) in
print(response as Any)
}, failure: { (error) in
print(error)
})

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot about adding custom URL Scheme to your app. You have to go to your target settings, open tab Info and add new URL scheme under "URL Types".  Remember to set "URL Schemes" to the same value as your callback URL scheme (it will be `myapp` in your case, but I will recommend you to change to something more specific to your app, like your bundle id). Also, you have to implement `application(_:open:options:)` method ([Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application)) in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey  : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  if (url.host == "myapp") {
    OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
  }
  return true
}
```

All these steps are written in this library read me: https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift

This is how `URL Types` section looks like (and remember that you have to put your callback URL scheme - `myapp`)
[image: URL Type panel]

Comment: bazyl87 - Thank you you for response, already i set URL Scheme and also set method in `AppDelegate`

Comment: In that case, I will suggest you check if callback URL is correctly configured in Hubspot, or maybe there is some issue with using `myapp://` as callback URL, maybe try something longer like: `myapp://oauth-callback/hubspot`

Comment: In hubspot there is option to set callback URL but its accepting only valid URL like https://www.google.com Its not accepting URL like `myapp://`                  
I tried with long URL like myapp://oauth-callback/hubspot but it also didn't work.      Its just keep loading after login in safari browser.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you shouldn't use Safari but use UIWebView or WKWebView, use https://your-callback and handle loading this callback by yourself. You should read ”Handle authorize URL” section in documents: https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/blob/master/README.md#handle-authorize-url and check